# Two files for different folders in gmail2gdrive script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail

I receive several files in one email.
I want to move each file to another folder in Google Drive.

I tried so and it does not work:

```
  { // example"
        "filter": "has:attachment from:example@gmail.com‏",
        "folder": "'example1'",
        "filenameFromRegexp": "example1.*\.pdf$",
        "folder": "'example2'",
        "filenameFromRegexp": "example2.*\.pdf$"
      }
```

I would appreciate their help

Original GitHub project:
https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive

Minimal, Reproducible Example:

config:

```
function getGmail2GDriveConfig() {
  return {
    // Global filter
    "globalFilter": "-in:trash -in:drafts -in:spam",
    // Gmail label for processed threads (will be created, if not existing):
    "processedLabel": "to-gdrive/processed",
    // Sleep time in milli seconds between processed messages:
    "sleepTime": 100,
    // Maximum script runtime in seconds (google scripts will be killed after 5 minutes):
    "maxRuntime": 280,
    // Only process message newer than (leave empty for no restriction; use d, m and y for day, month and year):
    "newerThan": "1m",
    // Timezone for date/time operations:
    "timezone": "GMT",
    // Processing rules:
    "rules": [
      { // example"
        "filter": "has:attachment from:example@gmail.com‏",
        "folder": "'example1'",
        "filenameFromRegexp": "example1.*\.pdf$",
        "folder": "'example2'",
        "filenameFromRegexp": "example2.*\.pdf$"
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

script:

```
function Gmail2GDrive() {
  if (!GmailApp) return; // Skip script execution if GMail is currently not available (yes this happens from time to time and triggers spam emails!)
  var config = getGmail2GDriveConfig();
  var label = getOrCreateLabel(config.processedLabel);
  var end, start, runTime;
  start = new Date(); // Start timer

  Logger.log("INFO: Starting mail attachment processing.");
  if (config.globalFilter===undefined) {
    config.globalFilter = "has:attachment -in:trash -in:drafts -in:spam";
  }

  // Iterate over all rules:
  for (var ruleIdx=0; ruleIdx<config.rules.length; ruleIdx++) {
    var rule = config.rules[ruleIdx];
    var gSearchExp  = config.globalFilter + " " + rule.filter + " -label:" + config.processedLabel;
    if (config.newerThan != "") {
      gSearchExp += " newer_than:" + config.newerThan;
    }
    var doArchive = rule.archive == true;
    var doPDF = rule.saveThreadPDF == true;

    // Process all threads matching the search expression:
    var threads = GmailApp.search(gSearchExp);
    Logger.log("INFO:   Processing rule: "+gSearchExp);
    for (var threadIdx=0; threadIdx<threads.length; threadIdx++) {
      var thread = threads[threadIdx];
      end = new Date();
      runTime = (end.getTime() - start.getTime())/1000;
      Logger.log("INFO:     Processing thread: "+thread.getFirstMessageSubject() + " (runtime: " + runTime + "s/" + config.maxRuntime + "s)");
      if (runTime >= config.maxRuntime) {
        Logger.log("WARNING: Self terminating script after " + runTime + "s");
        return;
      }
```

Comment: There is a difference between an object and a [mcve]

Comment: You're right. To that end, I linked to the GitHub project.

Comment: I don't follow links to offsite resources if you want my help  you will have to post your current code and explain the problem that your having with it.

Comment: script Too long, the site does not allow me to upload :(

Comment: That's why we require a [mcve].  We don't really want your entire code we just want the part that your having trouble with.  It's always better to build a special piece of code to highlight your unique question.  If don't wish to build a [mcve] then we will probably pass on this question.

Comment: I'm really trying, but I do not know how to shorten the code without missing important parts

Comment: Well if you having difficulty with the entire code then perhaps you should write the code yourself.

Comment: By the way the code easily fits into the question.  And it's not that complicated.

Comment: OK, I hope it's okay now

Comment: So where  is the problem?

Comment: I receive several files in one email. I want to move each file to another folder in Google Drive. I tried so and it does not work.

Comment: Have you communicated with the authors?

Comment: Yes, I have not received an answer yet

Comment: Well there's a good chance that the problem is in your config and they can help you with that a lot easier than we can.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not that complicated.  Here's a simple example in which I copied a coupled of files from emails I've just created.  It alternates between one of two folders but you could do anything you want.

```
function getAttachments() {
  const fldrids =['id1','id2'];
  const threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  threads.forEach(t=>{
    let msgs = t.getMessages();
    msgs.forEach(m=>{
      let sub = m.getSubject();
      let arr = m.getAttachments();
      if(arr.length) {
        arr.forEach((f,i)=>{
          let s =f.getDataAsString();
          let n = f.getName();
          DriveApp.getFolderById(fldrids[i%2]).createFile(n,s);
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```